# Find list of files that do not contain lower-case

Tags: awk, find, solaris

Tried a couple of dozen iterations of this, but can't seem to find the right combination.  I am using find to create a list of subdirectories and files.  I want to omit any filenames that contain lower case characters.  I am piping the output to awk to do further processing, so if it is easier there, that is fine.  I've tried both the find and the awk find (separately).  I am on Solaris 10 Unix if that makes any difference.

Input file list:

```
FOO/BAR.TXT
FOO/bar.TXT
FOO/BAT.TXT
BAZ/BAR.TXT
BAZ/baz.TXT
```

Desired output

```
FOO/BAR.TXT
FOO/BAT.TXT
BAZ/BAR.TXT
```

My find contains other exclusions, shown for example only

```
find ! \( -name 'FRED*' -o \
      -name '*JONES' -o \
      -name '*[a-z]8'  \)
```

I've also tried moving the lower-case negation to a nawk find, such as this:

```
find ! \( -name 'FRED*' -o \
      -name '*JONES'  \) 
    | nawk  -F'/' '!/a-z/ {print $2}'
```

Every iterations I have tried either gives me no output, or else all output including the filename with lowercase characters.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What should happen if the directory name contains lower case letters but the file name doesn't, e.g. `foo/BAR.TXT`? A character range in awk is written `[a-z]` just like you used in `find`, btw. Also, consider switching to /usr/xpg4/bin/awk instead of nawk as nawk is very old and pre-POSIX (which is why you need to use `[a-z]` instead of `[[:lower:]]`) while /usr/xpg4/bin/awk is more modern and [almost] POSIX.

Comment: `find . | grep -v \[a-z\]`

Comment: Instead of excluding `-name '*[a-z]8'`, try `-name '*[a-z]*'`

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider a directory with these files:

```
$ find . -type f
./FOO/BAT.TXT
./FOO/bar.TXT
./FOO/BAR.TXT
./BAZ/BAR.TXT
./BAZ/baz.TXT
```

To exclude all the files with one or more lower-case characters in their names:

```
$ find . -regextype egrep -type f -regex '[^[:lower:]]*'
./FOO/BAT.TXT
./FOO/BAR.TXT
./BAZ/BAR.TXT
```

Notes:

1. `[:lower:]` is the POSIX regex that matches any lower-case character. 
   This is unicode-safe.  `[^[:lower:]]` matches any character other than a lower-case letter.   `[^[:lower:]]*`  matches any sequence of characters that doesn't contain a lower case character.
2. Find's `-regex` applies this regex to the whole path and insists that it match from beginning to end as if it were `^[^[:lower:]]*$`.
3. Find supports a wide-variety of regex styles.  I chose the `egrep` style which includes the usual POSIX extended regular expressions.